# Installing Wine removed terminal. Please help

Tags: command-line, wine

All I typed was `sudo apt install wine` and now all of a sudden terminal is gone and I don't know why. I've even rebooted and yet still nothing. Please help!!

Comment: You can also try terminal through Dash (first icon in launcher). Just start typing first few letters.  Ctrl+alt+T short cut might have been nuked some how.

Comment: Still, nothing. CTRL+ALT+T doesn't work, it isn't in the dash menu, it isn't anywhere

Comment: You can press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to work in console mode and then Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to GUI.

Comment: I think there are alternate terminals you can install through the Software Center too.

Comment: Terminator works fine :)

Comment: If you are still using Xubuntu, Reinstall its terminal using `sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal`